# MI Redmi 2 stuck on Black Screen and not booting into Fastboot or recovery mode

Tags: custom-roms, fastboot, xiaomi, stock-rom, redmi-2

sometime ago I installed Linage OS 17.1 on my MI Redmi 2 (1GB) and also resized my system partition to 2.00GB and after some time I faced some auto-restarting problems then I decided to install the stock rom and when I went to install it, In MI flash tool it gave me a error  then I searched about it and found this article - https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/how-to-erase-partition-table-of-redmi-2-prime-2a.3520410/

Then I followed it but I used the rom I have downloaded from somewhere else and then I clicked flash, after 1-2hrs it was not completed then my friend suggested me to use the file given in this article and cancel the on going flashing process, so I canceled it and after that moment

it is Stuck on Black screen, and not even booting into fastboot or Recovery mode and when I connect it to a power-source or my laptop it doesn't responds at all.

So, if anyone from you have any solution please tell me...

-Thanks

Comment: unbelievable what stupid advice posted on xda. read the thread, of course device will brick if partition table is erased

Comment: hm, so I dont have a pin to sort the eld ports...

Comment: https://xiaomifirmwareupdater.com/miui/wt88047 https://github.com/bkerler/edl https://www.gsmtoolpro.com/p/blog-page_10.html

Comment: hm, I cant flash it because I cant go into fastboot or recovery mode...

Comment: and if you are on discord, can we talk on discord ?

Comment: of course not as you have erased fastboot and recovery. install Qualcomm HS-USB QDLoader 9008 Driver and use test point to boot into EDL mode. you can ask in that xda thread I may response there, as this is not the right place for discussion

Comment: which XDA thread ? BTW I live in India and this is almost my sleep time so can we do it after 10-11hrs ?

Comment: hey bro, will this work ? - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ePel-ToJYbQ

Comment: yes that's [deep flash cable](http://xiaomitips.com/guide/miui-deep-flash-engineering-cable-solution-to-non-edl-device) (data pin short-circuited to gnd)